# How to get url like in shopping apps (phone/android/xxx)?

Tags: url

I've been searching for quite some time on how to get url like on many pages where there are no visible php variables like f.e.:
**www.examplesite.com/users.php?name=someUser** to make it like **www.examplesite.com/users/someUser**
Probably my biggest problem is that I don't know how to search for it, since I don't know if it's part of PHP,HTML,JS or something else.
If anyone can link me to some tutorial about it, or something that explains it how it works that would work too.

Comment: try this keyword ".htaccess mod rewrite"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what architecture you are using. 
If you're running a apache Webserver this is e.g. done with a rewriterule placed in your .htaccess file.

For this the AllowOverride Option for your site needs to be turned on. See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Additionally in your local site folder you need to add a .htaccess file which turns the rewrite engine on:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

You can then add some rules after that. This is explained here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Oh okay, that's what I was looking for. I didn't know how it's called.  Thanks.